# What is the meaning of this structure in open cart programming "${$module['code']};"?

Tags: php, open-source

Hi I am new to opencart and currently facing one issue that not able to identify why it is coming
**"Notice: Undefined variable: dailydeal in ~/template/common/column_right.tpl on line 3"**

At line no 3 in this file the code written is as follows:

```
<?php echo ${$module['code']}; ?>
```

Can any one tell me the what is meaning of this syntax.  or how I can solve this issue.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It is possible that you're supposed to define the $dailydeal variable yourself and you haven't. But I have to it's been a long time since I've seen variable variables be useful and would question using a package that uses them.

Comment: Thanx for your suggestions my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

That's a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), from your error I can tell that:

```
echo $module['code']; // dailydeal
```

The `${$module['code']}` is the equivalent of `$dailydeal` (the variable content).

---

To avoid OpenCart throwing notices you can either lower your [error reporting](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) level, like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Or just fix the notice altogether, by adding an [`isset()`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) check:

```
if (isset(${$module['code']})) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: thanx Alix for your help , But my actual problem is still there as I am trying to create a new module and due to this notice it is not being displayed on my right bar.
If you can tell where I am making mistake will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

see this article [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)  there is written

> In order to use variable variables
>   with arrays, you have to resolve an
>   ambiguity problem. That is, if you
>   write $$a[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) then the parser needs to
>   know if you meant to use $a[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as a
>   variable, or if you wanted $$a as the
>   variable and then the [1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) index from
>   that variable. The syntax for
>   resolving this ambiguity is: ${$a[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)}
>   for the first case and ${$a}[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for
>   the second.

also read 
[language variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php)

Comment: Not the same, that's just accessing multi-dimensional array indexes with variables...